# Div messing up form input field spacing / height

Tags: css, forms, html, styling

I have the following problem:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, 2 input fields for some reason differ in spacing compared to the other fields. I searched for over an hour and removed almost all the styling but i cant find out what exactly is causing this.

Though i found out which DIV is causing the problem. For the form i am using an jquery validator with css styled error messages by using a field container for each input field and with a label for each input field (container is to postion / style EACH label).

The code is as follows: 
**The form HTML:**

```
<div class="signup_form">

   <form class="registratie_form" id = "register-form" action="register.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" >

                        <div class="fieldContainer">
                                <label for="voornaam"></label>    
                                <input type="text" id="voornaam" name="voornaam" required size='50' placeholder="Jouw voornaam" maxlenght='50' pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}">
                            </div>


                        <div class="fieldContainer">
                                <label for="achternaam"></label>
                                <input type="text" id="achternaam" name="achternaam" required size='50' placeholder="Jouw achternaam" maxlenght='50' pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
                             </div>


                        <div class="fieldContainer">
                                <label for="email"></label>
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required size='50' maxlenght='50' placeholder="Jouw e-mail adres">
                            </div>


                        <div class="fieldContainer">
                                    <label for="emailvalidation"></label>
                                    <input type="email" id="emailvalidation" name="emailvalidation" required size='50' maxlenght='50' placeholder="Bevestig jouw e-mail adres">
                            </div>


                        <div class="fieldContainer">
                                <label for="wachtwoord"></label>
                                <input type="password" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" required size='50' maxlenght='50' placeholder="Voer een wachtwoord in" pattern=".{4,}">
                            </div>                  
                               
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit">
                                               
           
</div>
           
</form>
```

Sorry for the dutch text ;) 
**The CSS is as follows:**

```
.fieldContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: -5px;
}
label.error {
    position: absolute;
    right: 143px;
    top: -25px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

.signup_form {position: relative; top: 40px; left:-75px; }
```

As you can notice in the image it is also only at the input fields of email and emailvalidation.. Anyone has a clue what is causing the problem?

Comment: It's probably some default browser style that is getting applied to `type="email"` and not `type="text"`. Make sure you apply any styles to both types.

Comment: There seem to be more styles affecting the results, plus you have a nesting problem with the form being closed outside the container div, which may also be affecting. Fix this and try to post here the address to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the code so we can see all the relevant elements.